# Does primalfin champion return removal and damage spells cast directly upon it?

Tags: hearthstone

Does primalfin champion return removal spells like siphon soul or damage spells like shadow bold? These are spells targeted at the minion, typically by the non controlling player. They are not shown as enchantments on its banner. Will they be returned upon death and to whom?

What about things like smuggler's run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primalfin Champion only returns spells **you** cast on it to your hand. So your opponents removal won't be returned.

As for which of your spells get returned:

- Spells that have a permanent effect such as "Blessing of Kings" **will** be returned.
- Spells that don't have a permanent effect but still target it like "Lay on Hands" or "Hammer of Wrath" **will** be returned.

Spells that will not be returned include:

- Secrets that affect it **won't** be returned.
- Global effects like "Equality" **won't** be returned.
- "Smuggler's Run" **won't** be returned.